# Program crashes when button text is updated

Tags: ios, objective-c

Sorry if the title seems a little ambiguous.

I'm calling a function, checkLogin, from within the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of my class. Here's the code for the method:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"UserLogin" accessGroup:nil];
NSString *activeUser = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
int length = [activeUser length];
NSLog(@"%d", length);

if (length > 0) {
    NSLog(@"Greater than 0");
    [testLabel setHidden:FALSE];
    [testLabel setText:@"Currently logged in"];
    /*

     To fix this, create a new button?

     */
    [loginButton setTitle:@"Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Less than 0");
    [testLabel setHidden:TRUE];
    [loginButton setTitle:@"Log In" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[loginButton setTitle:@"Log In" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
// Logout [keychain resetKeychainItem];
```

Whenever I attempt to change the title of the text, my program crashes, and I cannot understand why. Can anyone help me out with this?

The error I get is

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UIView.m:5781\ 2013-03-20 16:24:55.751 CompAir[5321:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after sending -viewDidLayoutSubviews to the view controller. FirstViewController's implementation needs to send
-layoutSubviews to the view to invoke auto layout.'}
```

Comment: Please post a (symbolic) stack trace and that will tell us all what's wrong.

Comment: Show us the code where `loginButton` and `textLabel` are created. And tell us if you are using ARC and if the properties for `loginButton` and `textLabel` are strong.

Comment: The problem isn't with testLabel, that updates fine. And loginButton was made using the GUI designer. I'm not using ARC

Comment: @Rothschild: Are you compiling for 6.0?

Comment: Are you programatically messing around with the autolayout stuff after the view appears? The exception suggests that something that was present when the screen first painted is no longer there.

Comment: Yeah, runs on my iOS device until that function is called and it hits the updating of the button text

Comment: @StephenDarlington Not that I'm aware of, I haven't written any code that plays with AutoLayout

Comment: I tried to update the text of another button within the same method and that works fine, obviously something is affecting loginButton, I'll attempt to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I've managed to fix the issue now. I, for some reason, had extra constraints on the width of my login button which weren't present on the other buttons (and hence why they worked). Problem solved after removing these constraints.